# Can I manipulate how sorted() organizes things?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm working with a large amount of data, (a list of tuples), that I would like to organize. To be more specific:

```
# my characters for the items in the strings are 1-9,a-e
# the results of my previous program produce a list of tuples
# e.g. ('string', int), where int is the count of occurrence of that string in my data
# my program currently lists them by count order, starting highest to lowest

>>> print results #results from the previous part of my code
[('7b7', 23522), ('dcd',23501)....('ccc',1)]

>>> for three_grams in results:
    print (sorted(three_grams))

[23522, '7b7']
[23501, 'dcd']
....
[1, 'ccc']
```

I'm not sure exactly why it switches the int and the string...
but I want to sort them just the opposite way. Ideally,

```
[('111',803), ('112', 2843), ('113', 10)....('fff', 12)]
```

Is there a way to manipulate how the `sorted()` function is sorting? Can I make it sort by `1-9a-e` in the string bits of the tuples instead?

(Also, my previous program for generating these results does not print results with zero counts, and I'd like some help with this. Not sure if I should post that here or make another discussion question with my entire code there? What would be stackoverflow etiquette? I'm still new)

Comment: `help(sorted)` in an interactive python interpreter session.

Comment: never use tuple as a variable name

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai, If you look in my comments, I'm not using it as a variable name(?? Or did I make it into a variable simply by calling it) I call "tuple" directly because i am working with just one tuple. (So in my shell it shows up highlighted)

Comment: `for tuple in results:` this is naming a variable as tuple :)

Comment: @SnarkShark it is changing `int and character` because you are sorting within the tuple and not on the list you could directly sort the results list if you want

Comment: @Peter Wood, Are you looking at my desired output or my current output? Because...Well.... that's just what it prints when I run the program...
Also, I thought I needed nltk to do sorting. Guess not. Thanks!

Comment: @SnarkShark this has nothing to do with NLTK  you just want to sort the list

Comment: @PeterWood, damn.... you're right... it returns [23522, '7b7']... :( I am full of mistakes today... how embarrassing :( Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sorting the individual result.

You need to sort *all* the results.

`sorted` can take a `key` parameter. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

We will use `result[0]` as the key for comparison, i.e. `'7b7'`, `'dcd'`, and `'ccc'`:

```
>>> results = [('7b7', 23522), ('dcd',23501), ('ccc',1)]

>>> sorted(results, key=lambda result: result[0])
[('7b7', 23522), ('ccc', 1), ('dcd', 23501)]
```

If you don't like the lambda, you can use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operators import itemgetter
>>> sorted(results, key=itemgetter(0))
[('7b7', 23522), ('ccc', 1), ('dcd', 23501)]
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting an error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Any idea why this might be? Does Python have anything like Prolog's "creep" ?

Comment: Could it be a Python3 and Python2.7 compatibility issue? When I look at help(sorted) in Python3 I see "sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)", but for Python2.7  "sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)." For 2.7 it requires an extra element? Or should it not matter?

Comment: @SnarkShark Pretty sure the error message will have more detail. What line is it on, what's the line of code?

Comment: @SnarkShark No, there are defaults defined (the `None` values). You're probably missing a parenthesis or something.

Comment: You're right! I will read more about sorting so that I don't have these problems in the future. Thanks for taking the time to help me! 
By chance (if its simple), do you know how I could also include tuples that have a 0 count? (They were never counted in my original code which used nltk.trigrams() to get my data). I'll read more and maybe ask later, if you think that's better stackoverflow etiquette.

Comment: You're welcome. Ask it as another question. Questions (not just answers) should be helpful to others, so the more precise and constrained you are in your problem statement the better for everyone. We're not just working to solve your problem, but the category of your problem, for others. Also, I know nothing of `nltk` (c:

Answer (score 0):

You could define a dictionary like so which is kind of like a hexadecimal system (except this is base 14):

```
valuesdict = {'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11, 'e': 14, 'd': 13, '1': 1, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8}
```

Add a function which calculates the decimal value(base 10) of the string in the base 14 system.

```
base = 14
def base10value(text):  

    count = len(text)-1
    finalValue = 0

    for character in text:
        number = valuesdict[character]
        finalValue += number*math.pow(base,count)
        count -= 1

    return finalValue
```

And then use a lambda function on your list of tuples

```
print sorted(tuple,key = lambda x: base10value(x[0]))
```

Comment: Hmmm... I get an error with the print statement. "TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable". Is this perhaps because my 1-9a-f alphabet are in strings within the tuples? I understand that the base10value() uses the values from the dictionary, so it shouldn't be a problem... Any ideas as to why I might be getting this error?

Comment: The base10value has a string argument and in the lambda function, it takes as input the first element of the tuple (which is a string).Try manually calling the base10value function with arbitrary string values to check if it works.